# Fill in a partly filled in table such that it makes the magma $(M,*)$ associative, commutative, has an identity element and has no zero-elements.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, semigroups, binary-operations, magma, cayley-table

Below is a partly filled in table for a binary operation ($*$) on the set $M=\{a,b,c,d\}$. I am trying to fill in the rest such that the magma $(M,*)$ becomes associative, commutative, has an identity element and has no zero-elements.

[image: Partly filled in table]

---

Using the fact that $(M,*)$ is supposed to be commutative we can fill in a few cells and get:

[image: Filledin2]

---

Now we want the magma to be associative too, so I can get the following information:

$(c*a)*b = c*(a*b)$

$a*b = c*b$

$b*c = b = c*b$

and we end up with:

[image: Filledin3]

---

$(a*c)*d = a*(c*d)$

$a*d = a*c$

$a*d = a = d*a$

and we end up with:

[image: Filledin4]

---

$(b*c)*d = b*(c*d)$

$b*d = b*c$

$b*d = b = d*b$

and we end up with:

[image: Filledin5]

---

Now we see that $d$ must be the identity element due to the **d-row** being equal to the **heading row** and the **d-column** is equal to the **heading column**.

we end up with:

[image: Filledin6]

---

Now this is where I get stuck, I can't figure out what the two last cells need to be. I have gained some information though, the magma $(M,*)$ does not form a group. This due to the fact that we for example have duplicate entries on the a-row [_ b a a] which would not be allowed if the magma was a group. We also notice that not every element seems to have an inverse, which again is not allowed if the magma was to be a group.

Comment: I guess it's because there are multiple options.

Comment: No, the table should only be able to be filled in exactly one way in order to satisfy the requirements stated.

Comment: Indeed, probably yes. We have $a*a=a*c*c=a*c=a$. If there's no zero element, then $b*b\ne b$.

Comment: The most immediate inference is that $b*b\ne b$.

Comment: @Berci According to what you said we now also know $a*a = a$ and $b*b \neq b$. Why exactly is $b*b \neq b$? It feels like I am missing something obvious. Eitherway we know $b*b$ can't be equal to $b$ or $d$. So we know that $b*b$ is equal to either $a$ or $c$. So close, yet I can't figure this last cell out.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott How come?

Comment: @NoName123: You can’t have a zero element.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott What exactly is a "zero element", I thought I knew but apparently it seems that I do not.

Comment: @NoName123: It’s an [absorbing element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_element): an element $z$ with the property that $z*a=z$ for all $a$. $0$ is such an element for ordinary multiplication.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ah alright, that was very informative. I had a slight misunderstanding of the term. So we know $b*b$ can't be equal to $b$ (cause no zero elements allowed) or $d$ due to the fact that $b*b=d$ would imply that $b$ is its own inverse, which is not possible. Only the identity element can be its own inverse right?. It's then either $a$ or $c$, I still can't figure out which one it is though.

Comment: @NoName123: Sorry: I misread your comment, and you should ignore mine, which I’ll delete.

Comment: @NoName123: it can happen even in groups to have an *involutive* element $b$ for which $b*b=1$, as geometric transformations, these are the various *reflections*.

Answer (score 2):

Since $ac = a$ and $a =c^2$, you have $a^2 =aa=ac^2 = ac = a$. I claim that $b^2 = a$. Indeed, if $b^2 = 1$, then since $ab = b$, $1 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = a^2b^2 = a^2$, a contradiction, since $a^2 = a$. If $b^2 = c$, then since $ab =b$, one has $abb = bb$, that is, $ac = c$, a contradiction, since $ac = a$. Finally, if $b^2 = b$, then $b$ is a zero of the monoid, which is excluded. This proves the claim.

Altogether the identity of the monoid is $1$, there is a non-regular element $c$ and the minimal ideal is the group of order $2$ consisting of the idempotent $a$ and the element $b$.

Comment: What do you mean with "the idempotent $b$"? Shouldn't an idempotent be a member $x$ such that $x^2=x$?

Comment: @amsra Ooops, you're right: $a$ is the idempotent and $b$ is the other element of the group. Fixed.